# Sets with the most zombies

Tags: sets, minifigures

My kids love LEGO or compatible brands sets with zombies (e.g. Monster Fighters from LEGO and Cityville Invasion from Kre-O).

I was wondering which LEGO or compatible brand set has the most zombies included, in the sense of mini-figurines.

For instance, the LEGO 850487-1 set is very cool, but only has one zombie.

Answer (score 4):

Searching Zombies Minifigs on Bricklink I find 22 official Lego zombies, including the Monster Fighters, Minecraft, Scooby Doo, Ghostbusters, Pirates of the Caribbean, and several Mini figures from the collections.

http://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=zombie#T=M

Most of them are one offs in the set.

The most I found was three zombies in a set.  There were two sets:

Pirates of the Caribbean 4195-1 Queen Annes Revenge: Has three zombie pirates and a skeleton which I'm not counting as a zombie:

[image]

Monster Fighters 9465-1 The Zombies Set has Three Zombies, a zombie bride, a zombie groom, and a zombie driver:
[image]

Comment: 4195-1 is super cool! My kids will love it, thanks

Answer (score 4):

I would probably suggest the Call of duty zombie sets by Mega BLoks. Most of them include at least 4 figures, although they are highly detailed, so they might be a bit too scary for your kids. For reference, try [this site](https://collectors.megabloks.com/en-us/call-of-duty/playsets?meta:type=zombies). If you're looking specifically only for the figures themselves, I suggest getting the zombie packs. For example:
[image]
or
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Please be more specific about parameters of preference. McFarlane Toys released a series of brick-based sets that are high-detail and one-off. I am not 100% sure if they are Lego compatible, and the figures have limited articulation. If you are just looking for minifigs, you are better off searching a site like BrickLink. Anyway, for any given theme that has zombies (in any brand), the 'big' set of that theme is extremely likely to have the most zombie figures.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the new **The Walking Dead** unofficial sets, they will used for recreate the Negan brutal scene or something